# Can InAppSettingsKit be used just for Settings.app

Tags: iphone, ios, inappsettingskit

I would like to use InAppSettingsKit only for displaying the settings in the Settings.app of the iPhone. I have different custom settings for in-app settings. Is this possible and how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To support traditional Settings.app panes, the app must include a Settings.bundle with at least a Root.plist to specify the connection of settings UI elements with NSUserDefaults keys. InAppSettingsKit basically just uses the same Settings.bundle to do its work. This means there's no additional work when you want to include a new settings parameter. It just has to be added to the Settings.bundle and it will appear both in-app and in Settings.app. All settings types like text fields, sliders, toggle elements, child views etc. are supported.

The plists are searched in this order:

InAppSettings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.inApp.plist  - InAppSettings.bundle/FILE.inApp.plist
   InAppSettings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.plist
   InAppSettings.bundle/FILE.plist
   Settings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.inApp.plist
   Settings.bundle/FILE.inApp.plist Settings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.plist
   Settings.bundle/FILE.plist

I hope it helps!!

*EDIT:*

The InAppSettingsKit library searches automatically on all your settings bundles, in that order I wrote before. However, the settings.app only searches into the `Settings.bundle`. So, if you want a separated settings file for your app (using InAppSettingsKit) you can create a `Settings.bundle` for your settings app and a, e.g., `InAppSettings.bundle`for your in-app settings.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still not sure if this has answered my question. Does it mean whatever settings I add will be displayed in both in-app and Settings app ? I want them to appear only in the Settings apps. I am not sure how the connection is made between the settings.bundle and the InAppSettings. Settings.bundle only offers the default controls. How does it know to use the InAppSettings custom classes. Where am I linking them together ?

Comment: So you want a InAppSettingsKit different to the Settings app, don't you??

Comment: Yes. You are right, I want a InAppSettingsKit just for the Settings app of iPhone. I am not using InAppSettingsKit for the in-app settings page. I am not sure how to link the Settings bundle and the InAppSettingsKit.